# F# Type Providers vs. Lisp macros

Tags: f#, macros, lisp, metaprogramming, type-providers

I've been reading about F# 3.0 type providers (e.g. [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156509.aspx)) and it seems that they are based on a kind of compile-time code generation. In that respect I was wondering how they compare against Lisp macros. It would seem that both F# 3.0 type providers and Lisp macros allow user code to execute at compile time and introduce new types available to the compiler. Can anyone shed some light on the issue and nuances involved?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is some overlap between F# type providers and meta-programming techniques from other languages, but I agree with Daniel that they do not have much in common. F# has some other meta-programming techniques like quotations that are perhaps closer to LISP macros.

In particular:

- LISP macros are typically used to transform expressions (you can take a LISP expression and either interpret it or transform it and then execute it). Note that the transformation takes a LISP expression as an input - on the other hand, type providers can only take very limited parameters (strings, integers).
- Quotations are more similar. They can be used to process F# expression - you can treat a piece of F# code as data and interpret it or transform it. The transformation takes (a sub-set of) an F# expression, but it typically does not execute it.
- Type providers are used purely to generate *types*. Since LISP is dynamically typed, this is not really a problem that you'd have in LISP. However, it is a sort of code-generation (a form of metaprogramming that you can certainly do in LISP).

Comment: Seems like the biggest advantage of Lisp macros over quotations is compile-time execution. F# doesn't have anything like that, does it?

Comment: @Daniel - I guess type providers (TP) and quotations (Q) are two extreme sides of macros. Q allow expression manipulation, but do not support compile-time execution. TP do not support expression manipultation, but do support compile-time execution (resulting in generated types).

Comment: However, LISP macros do not support _compile-time_ execution, they evaluate at _run-time_, but that's a lot easier with dynamic typing.

Comment: @TomasPetricek: LISP macros does allow compile time execution. Basically when the macro is expanded you can execute any code i.e the whole language is available to you. For example embedding a "compile date time" in code can be done

Comment: @TomasPetricek, what? Lisp macros are executed in compile time only, unless you're compiling something in runtime. And typing is *totally* irrelevant to the macro expansion (see Nemerle, MetaOCaml and even Template Haskell for examples).

Answer (score 7):

An interesting aspect of F# type providers is that they work not only at compile-time, but at *design-time*, that is, in a way that interacts with the full IDE tooling.  Type Providers provide 'types' from an external schematized data source, but the implementation mechanism also enables lots of IDE tooling, including IntelliSense (identifier auto-completion), documentation, data tooltips, etc.  Combined with the interactive REPL, this affords easy exploration of unfamiliar data sets in a way that is not quite like the experience in any other language.

Comment: Um. Macros do this too. If you define a macro, your Lisp IDE can give you intellisense and argument hints about it, as well as show you intermediate expansions. Documentation also still works. Not that it isn't cool, but it's available to both sides of that `vs.` in the question.

Comment: @Inaimathi: pointer to such an IDE? I'd be interested to try it out - so far I'm doing LISP in the plainest way (edit, send to repl via slime, run).

Comment: @ttsidoras - Emacs+SLIME gives you hints at the minibuffer when you've got your system loaded. I'm reasonably sure LispWorks does something similar, but I don't use it.

Answer (score 7):

F# Type providers are a very specific case of compile time code generation i.e they are meant to solve a specific kind of problem by compile time code generation. They allow you to generate new types at compile time.

LISP macros are a more generic approach to meta-programming and hence cater to a lot of use cases. Macro's basically take input as S-expression (code or data) and emit other S-expression .

So a type provider can be implemented using macro easily, whereas you cannot cover the whole range of "what macros can do" with type providers.

Comment: _"Type provider can be implemented using macro easily"_ - it may not be as easy and straightforward. I think there would be some interesting issues: 1.) Type providers generate types on demand as they are accessed by the caller code. This is probably doable with macros (?) but it is no longer `expr -> expr` transformation 2.) Type providers are not just compiler feature. An integral part is the IDE experience, which relies on types and I'm not sure it would have direct equivalent in the LISP world (again, this is doable in some ways, but perhaps not quite easily)

Comment: @TomasPetricek: Type providers would make more sense in a statically typed language and not so in a dynamically typed language like Lisp. In Lisp, it would make sense to create `function providers` i.e macros creating Lisp code for proxy functions that calls a remote web service.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not familiar with Lisp macros, but macros in general are used for meta programming (to save typing and add control constructs to the language). Type providers, on the other hand, generate strongly-typed APIs for external data sources.

I can't think of anything besides compile time "expansion" that they have in common.